# How to pass a query in a jquery AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am very new to AJAX requests and server programming. This is for a school project. I want to put the SID I generated in the parameter for this request. I am also attempting to pass in a colors object, and a string representing a level, as well as a string representing a font. This is what the AJAX call looks like:

```
$.ajax( {
      url : '/wordgame/api/v1/' + sid,
      method : 'POST',
      data : {level : level, font : font, colors : colors},
      success : showModal
   } );
```

I am sending this AJAX request to this endpoint that creates a game and assigns it to an SID:

```
router.post('/wordgame/api/v1/:sid', function(req, res, next) {
      var result = createGame(req.body.colors, req.body.font, req.body.level);
      [sidDB][req.params.sid][result.id] = result;
      res.send(result);
});
```

(sidDB is simply a database of many SIDs, however for this project I am only using one. )

I am receiving a 500 error, and I noticed that when I inspect the document, the SID is NOT being passed into the parameter of the request like I want it to.

(Also note I am running this through Node.js with the Express framework).

My entire index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var uuid = require('uuid');
var router = express.Router();

// a database of SIDs that each hold their own array of games
var sidDB = {};

var fonts = {
  this.helvetica = {
    category: 'Sans-serif',
    family: 'Neue Helvetica',
    rule: 'Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    url: 'https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica?QueryFontType=Web&src=GoogleWebFonts'
  }
};

function Game( colors, font, level) {
  function guid() {
      function s4() {
         return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
      }
      return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
         s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
   }

   this.id = guid();

   this.colors = {
     guessBackground : colors.guess,
     textBackground : colors.fore,
     wordBackground : colors.word
   }

   this.font = font;

   this.level = level;

   if (level == "easy") {
     this.level = { name : "easy", minLength : 3, maxLength : 5, rounds : 8 }
   } else if (level == "medium") {
     this.level = { name : "medium", minLength : 4, maxLength : 10, rounds : 7 }
   } else if (level == "hard") {
     this.level = { name : "hard", minLength : 9, maxLength : 300, rounds : 6 }
   } else {
     // throw an error
   }

   this.guesses = {};

   this.remainingRounds = this.level.rounds;

   this.status = "unfinished";

   this.target = null;

   this.timestamp = new Date();

   this.timeToComplete = null;

   this.view = null;

}

var createGame = function(colors, font, level) {
  var result = new Game(colors, font, level);
  return result;
}

// The actual endpoints for this project



router.get('/wordgame', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile( 'index.html', { root : __dirname + "/../public" } );
} );

router.get('/wordgame/api/v1/sid', function(req, res, next) {
  // Must create an SID every time app starts.
  var result = uuid();
  sid = result;
  res.send(result);
});

router.get('/wordgame/api/v1/meta', function(req, res, next) {

  res.send(result);
});

router.get('/wordgame/api/v1/meta/fonts', function(req, res, next) {


  res.send(result);
});


router.get('/wordgame/api/v1/:sid', function(req, res, next) {
  var result = gamesDb;
   res.send( result );
} );

// CREATE GAME HERE

router.post('/wordgame/api/v1/:sid', function(req, res, next) {
  var result = createGame(req.body.colors, req.body.font, req.body.level);
  [sidDB][req.params.sid][result.id] = result;
  res.send(result);
});

router.get('/wordgame/api/v1/:sid/:gid', function(req, res, next) {


  res.send(result);
});

router.post('/wordgame/api/v1/:sid/:gid/guesses', function(req, res, next) {


  res.send(result);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Assuming sid is set on the client-side, this is most likely related to your routing configuration in express, rather than an ajax issue.  You should post your routes as well.

Comment: @anthonL I added the entire index.js file from my routes directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have some errors and I have changed a little the code and separate the api. First you need your index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var uuid = require('uuid');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function(){});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, authorization");
next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use('/wordgame', require('./games.api')());
```

and then you need the api file called games.api.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var uuid = require('uuid');
var sidDB = {};
var gamesDb = {};
var fonts = {
  helvetica: {
    category: 'Sans-serif',
    family: 'Neue Helvetica',
rule: 'Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
url: 'https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica?QueryFontType=Web&src=GoogleWebFonts'
  }
};
function Game( colors, font, level) {
  function guid() {
      function s4() {
         return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
     s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
   }
   this.id = guid();
   this.colors = {
     guessBackground : colors.guess,
     textBackground : colors.fore,
     wordBackground : colors.word
   }
   this.font = font;
   this.level = level;
 if (level == "easy") {
  this.level = { name : "easy", minLength : 3, maxLength : 5, rounds : 8 }
  } else if (level == "medium") {
  this.level = { name : "medium", minLength : 4, maxLength : 10, rounds : 7 }
  } else if (level == "hard") {
  this.level = { name : "hard", minLength : 9, maxLength : 300, rounds : 6 }
   } else {
     // throw an error
   }
  this.guesses = {};
  this.remainingRounds = this.level.rounds;
  this.status = "unfinished";
  this.target = null;
  this.timestamp = new Date();
  this.timeToComplete = null;
  this.view = null;
 }

var createGame = function(colors, font, level) {
  var result = new Game(colors, font, level);
  return result; 
}

module.exports = function() {
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile( 'index.html', { root : __dirname + "/../public" } );
} );
router.get('/api/v1/sid', function(req, res) {
  // Must create an SID every time app starts.
  var result = uuid();
  sid = result;
  res.send(result);
});
router.get('/api/v1/meta', function(req, res) {

  res.send(result);
});
router.get('/api/v1/meta/fonts', function(req, res) {
  res.send(result);
});
router.get('/api/v1/:sid', function(req, res) {
  var result = gamesDb;
  res.send( result );
 } );
router.post('/api/v1/:sid/', function(req, res) {
console.log("req.body", req.body, req.query, req.params);
  var result = createGame(req.body.colors, req.body.font, req.body.level);
  sidDB[req.params.sid][result.id] = result;
  res.send(result);
});
router.get('/api/v1/:sid/:gid', function(req, res) {
  res.send(result);
});
router.post('/api/v1/:sid/:gid/guesses', function(req, res) {
  res.send(result);
});
return router;

};
```

Then you will have the ss code working but you need to do Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests in your ClientSide, you can search in web how to do this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick review and found that sidDB is an Object so should change this:

```
[sidDB][req.params.sid][result.id] = result;
```

for this:

```
sidDB[req.params.sid][result.id] = result;
```

try it and let me know.

Regards,

**More changes**

You need to decode the url but it is necessary to use an extension, try add this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

And from app use the router if you have problems.

Regards,

Comment: That might have been a problem but it didn't solve the 500 error. I believe it has something to do with the way I am passing the SID in my parameters but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have add some to my response, check it and let me know.